# Is there a way to implement the Catcher and Sentry packages on flutterflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

i'm building a flutterflow app and i'm in need of some package to catch and handle errors on the app... most of the searches throw me on this two:
https://pub.dev/packages/catcher
https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter
but as it seems, it's only for pure flutter. Is there a way to implement them on flutterflow ? or another package compatible with flutterflow that catches and handles errors ?

i've tried to implement them as widgets and actions, but it gives me package errors, and according to the documentation, you'd have to put them outside of the MaterialApp class. Is it possible to do this on flutterflow ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to integrate it externally after exporting the code.
I personally wrote a small dart script that I run during my CI/CD pipeline that patches the codebase before build to add the relevant changes to my code for Catcher2.